# Webpack: Hide some modules printed by webpack --display-modules --display-reasons

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, webpack, node-modules

### Question

Is it possible to specify modules to be hidden (ignored) in printed output by `webpack --display-modules --display-reasons`?

---

### Setup

**`structure`**

```
.
├── build
│   └── index.js
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── hello
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── util
│   │   └── index.js
│   └── world
│       └── index.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

**`package.json`**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --display-modules --display-reasons"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.13.1"
  }
}
```

**`src/index.js`**

```
import hello from './hello'
import world from './world'

console.log(`${hello()} ${world()}`);
```

**`src/hello/index.js`**

```
import util from '../util';
const _ = require('lodash');

const hello = () => _.capitalize(`hello${util()}`);

export default hello
```

**`src/world/index.js`**

```
import util from '../util';
const _ = require('lodash');

const world = () => _.capitalize(`world${util()}`);

export default world
```

**`src/util/index.js`**

```
export default () => '!'
```

**`webpack.config.js`**

```
module.exports = {

  entry: './src/index.js',

  output: {
    filename: './build/index.js'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: 'es2015'
        }
      }
    ]
  }

};
```

---

### Motivation

By running `webpack` I get this *stunning* program in **`build/index.js`** which prints:

```
Hello! World!
```

More interesting part is in output printed by `webpack --display-modules --display-reasons`:

[image: output printed by webpack --display-modules --display-reasons]

This output is very powerful:

- immediately see project structure
- recognise which modules are required by other modules
- how many times those modules are reused
- where those modules are required in other modules
- used module format
- is it my module or from node_modules
- looks super cool

Mentioned above pros connivence me to use this output in daily work.

But can be problem with it.

---

### Problem

When I use big external package with a lot of modules it can blur my output from previous picture. You can see it when add for example `core-js` to my files:

**`src/index.js (modified)`**

```
require('core-js'); // new problematic package

import hello from './hello'
import world from './world'

console.log(`${hello()} ${world()}`);
```

Now my output printed by `webpack --display-modules --display-reasons` looks like this:

[image: output printed by webpack --display-modules --display-reasons with core-js]

This output is **quite long** (it's hard to scroll to top). `core-js` blooded my previously output and I lost mentioned previous pros of analyze it.

---

### Tips

- problematic output isn't always at the end
- problem isn't related only with `core-js` (it's only example)
- switching to pre-build sources isn't solution
- require of problematic package must occurs in source `.js` files not in `webpack.config.js`

Comment: There is parameter called [--display-exclude](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/bin/webpack.js#L56), but I didn't found any examples. You can try it yourself :)

Comment: @BobSponge It work perfectly - write an answer and get the fame!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In webpack there is undocumented option [--display-exclude](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/bin/webpack.js#L56) which, as described in source code, *exclude modules in the output*.

This is exactly what you need, so, pass this parameter to webpack cli:

```
webpack --display-modules --display-reasons --display-exclude="core-js"
```

Comment: somebody knows how to use this parameter passing more than 1 folder (array or regexp) ? I am going crazy to exclude node_modules AND a custom folder

Comment: This param processed by `ModuleFilenameHelpers.matchPart`, so it is regexp.

Answer (score 4):

To exclude more than one folder add the following to `webpack.config.js`

```
 stats: {
     exclude: [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "jam",
        "components",
        "my-custom-folder"
     ]
 }
```

without using `--display-exclude`